# Error while creating own linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a program that reads from a text file and stores the words into a singly linked list. I'm supposed to create my own linked list as opposed to using the STL. I've tried looking up a fair number of tutorials, but I keep getting an error on the variable "head." It says "a value type of Node cannot be used to initialize an entity of type Node"

This is List.cpp:

```
#include "List.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void List::add(string s){
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->addString(s);
    newNode->setNext(NULL);

    Node *temp = head;

    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        while(temp->Next() != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->Next();
        }

        temp->setNext(newNode);
    }
    else
    { 
        head = newNode;
    }

}
void List::print(){
Node *temp = head;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"EMPTY"<< endl;
        return;
    }
    if(temp->Next() == NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->Word();
        cout<< "-->";
        cout<< "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else
    { do{
        cout<<temp->Word();
        cout<<"-->";
        temp = temp->Next();
    }
    while( temp != NULL);
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
}
void List::read(ifstream& fin){
    while(!fin.eof())
        {
            fin>>sTemp;
            add(sTemp);
        }

}
```

This is Node.h

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>
class Node
{ string val;
Node* next;
public: 
    Node(void){}
    Node(string s)
    {
        val = s;
        next = nullptr;
    }
    void addString(string aString){ val = aString;};
    void setNext(Node* aNext){next = aNext;};
    string Word(){return val;};
    Node* Next(){return next;}; 
    string sTemp;
};
```

This is List.h

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
class List{
    Node* head;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void print();
    void add(string s);
    void find(string key);
    void read(ifstream& fin);
    string sTemp;
}
```

Under the actual List.cpp, it gives me an error when I say Node *temp = head; with the aforementioned error. Any reason why and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that in `List.cpp` you've included `Node.h` twice.

- directly includes List.h which itself includes Node.h
- directly includes Node.h

I'm surprised that the compiler didn't warn you about this.  It seems instead that it chose to redefine `Node` hence you end up with two `Node` values which aren't compatible.  You need to add include guards to your header files to prevent double includes

List.h

```
#if !LIST_H
#define LIST_H
...
#endif
```

Node.h

```
#if !NODE_H
#define NODE_H
...
#endif
```

Also note that it's generally speaking considered bad practice to have `using` statements in header files.  Instead use namespace qualified names in headers and put the `using` statements into the .cpp files.

Comment: Thanks! So {using} belongs in .cpp files, not .h files. Got it!